# Framework Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, framework, laravel-5.3

Sou novo com o Framework Laravel 5.3 e não consigo mudar o index padrão, que é o arquivo `/Resources/views/welcome.blade.php`.

Tentei duas coisas:

1. Mudar o arquivo padrão;
2. Criar um novo arquivo e trocar a rota em `/routes/web.php`.

Nesses dois caminhos, a página permaneceu a mesma.

Comment: Como foi a tentativa de mudar o arquivo padrão? O que você fez? E a rota que tentou criar, como era? Coloque mais detalhes e os trechos relevantes de código! Use o link [edit] acima.

Answer (score 1):

> e não consigo mudar o index padrão, que é o arquivo /Resources/views/welcome.blade.php.

Você alterou o `welcome.blade.php`, salvou após mudar, e a alteração não apareceu ao atualizar o navegador?
E na outra opção, você criou um arquivo `nome_novo.blade.php` no diretório das views e adicionou a rota usando `nome_novo`?

Answer (score 0):

Vá até o arquivo que contém as rotas:

> application/routes.php

e defina o controller para redirecionar para sua view

```
    Route::get('/', function()
{
    // controller para seu template
});
```